# Update table based on condition that uses previous row

Tags: sql, sqlite

Table `games`:

```
CREATE TABLE "games" (
    "match_id"    INTEGER,
    "player"      TEXT,
    "opponent"    TEXT,
    "n_games"     INTEGER,
    "games_won"   INTEGER,
    "games_lost"  INTEGER,
    "n_points"    INTEGER,
    "points_won"  INTEGER,
    "points_lost" INTEGER
);
```

Sample data :

```
INSERT INTO games (`match_id`, `player`, `opponent`, `n_games`, `games_won`, `games_lost`, `n_points`, `points_won`, `points_lost`) VALUES
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '2', '2', '0'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '3', '2', '1'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '4', '2', '2'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '5', '2', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '6', '2', '4'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '7', '2', '5'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '8', '2', '6'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '9', '2', '7'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '10', '2', '8'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '11', '2', '9'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '12', '2', '10'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '13', '3', '10'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '1', '0', '0', '14', '3', '11'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '2', '0', '2'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '4', '1', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '5', '2', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '6', '3', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '7', '4', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '8', '5', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '9', '5', '4'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '10', '5', '5'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '11', '5', '6'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '12', '5', '7'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '13', '5', '8'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '14', '5', '9'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '15', '6', '9'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '16', '6', '10'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '17', '6', '11'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '2', '0', '2'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '3', '0', '3'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '4', '0', '4'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '5', '1', '4'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '6', '1', '5'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '7', '1', '6'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '8', '1', '7'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '9', '1', '8'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '10', '1', '9'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '1', '11', '1', '10'),
  ('1', 'A', 'B', '2', '0', '2', '12', '1', '11');
```

Due to an error in scraping I need to edit the above data.

> The winner of a game is the first player to score 11 points or, in
> case of a tie at 10, the first player to create a difference of 2
> points after the tie (12-10, 14-12, 15-17).

The first game of the data is correct. After `B` scores 11-3 `A` loses the game which can be seen as `n_games` += 1 and `games_lost` += 1. However, the rest of the match is wrong. How do I update `n_games`, `games_won`, `games_lost` by above mentioned criteria?

Desired output:

| match_id | player | opponents | n_games | games_won | games_lost | n_points | points_won | points_lost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 2 | 4 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 2 | 5 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 9 | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 12 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 13 | 3 | 10 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 | 0 | 0 | 14 | 3 | 11 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 4 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 8 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 9 | 5 | 4 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 11 | 5 | 6 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 12 | 5 | 7 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 13 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 14 | 5 | 9 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 15 | 6 | 9 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 16 | 6 | 10 |
| 1 | A | B | 2 | 0 | 1 | 17 | 6 | 11 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 0 | 4 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 8 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 10 | 1 | 9 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 11 | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | A | B | 3 | 0 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 11 |

Answer (score 0):

If rows are inserted in the order by which the points are played, we can use ROWID as a temporal order of the match.

`n_games`, `games_won` and `games_lost` increments every time `n_points` restarts from 1. You don't need to check how many points the game lasted.
First you need to correct the `n_games` column:

```
UPDATE games
SET n_games = 
    (SELECT count(*) FROM games g 
     WHERE g.match_id = games.match_id AND g.ROWID <= games.ROWID AND g.n_points=1 );
```

Then you can group by `match_id, n_games` to get the final score for each game and use it to update `games_won` and `games_lost`:

```
WITH final_scores AS (
    SELECT match_id, n_games, max(n_points) as last_point, points_won, points_lost
    FROM games g
    GROUP BY match_id, n_games
)
UPDATE games
SET games_won = (SELECT count(n_games) FROM final_scores fs WHERE fs.match_id = games.match_id AND fs.n_games < games.n_games AND fs.points_won > fs.points_lost),
games_lost = (SELECT count(n_games) FROM final_scores fs WHERE fs.match_id = games.match_id AND fs.n_games < games.n_games AND fs.points_won < fs.points_lost);
```

[Here is a Fiddle with your data](https://dbfiddle.uk/T5g_8EHI)

Note: Sqlite will take points_won and points_lost from the same row where max(n_points) is taken, since they are not in the GROUP BY clause.